# What search engine does Stack Exchange use?

Tags: support, search, search-engine

I am curious, just wanted to know what search engine is being used by Stack Exchange for the per-site searching?

Answer (score 11):

They are using [elasticsearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/) now:

> After the performance problems we have run into with [Lucene.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucene#Lucene.NET) we've
>   decided to make a change, we're moving the network on to
>   elasticsearch.

[more...](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160100)

Answer (score 6):

Stack Overflow & Stack Exchange are now using [Lucene .Net](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/stack-overflow-search-now-81-less-crappy/)