# Area 51 Mobile Site

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, area-51, mobile-web

All the other sites have a mobile version, but Area 51 doesn't. Why not? Can it be added?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Area 51 is actually a separate codebase from the rest of the Stack Exchange sites.

At this point it is sort of on its last legs as we're working towards ["Area 52"](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5089/next-generation-of-area-51/5102#5102), which is probably/hopefully not going to be actually called "Area 52".

We currently don't have any plans to put a lot of development effort into Area 51 as a result, and that includes creating a mobile interface for it. No promises at this point, but fingers crossed for a mobile-friendly Area 52. :)

Comment: But why can't there be a mobile site if all of them use the same general format, albeit a different codebase. Plus the few modifications that are specific to a51. I.e. same general span/div tags for formatting

Comment: Area 51 doesn't use anywhere near the same "general format" as the rest of the sites.

Comment: @ColeJohnson The discussion area of Area 51 is sort of similar to the rest of the sites, but the main part where all the proposals are is quite different. Even if it were similar, it'd still take time and some effort to create a mobile interface and make sure things were working right. We have enough of other things going on right now (such as [updating the search engine](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160100/a-new-search-engine-for-stack-exchange)) that making a mobile interface for a platform that's on the way to being deprecated is just not high on the priority list.

Comment: @AdamLear Is area 52 a thing that is still bring worked on? This post is from 2012 so just checking.

Comment: @thesecretmaster Honestly, not really. I'd love to burn A51 to the ground and build something better in its place, but other priorities have come up.

Comment: Maybe 52 stands for 2052... :D