# Why can't I sign in to Area51 automatically?

Tags: support

If I sign in to just one SE community, I'm automatically signed in to all other SE communities that I'm a member of. But this doesn't happen when I visit Area51.

There, I have to sign in separately, although I'm already online on other communities. Why is that?

Comment: For the same reasons as in http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/160437/270345, I assume