# Why doesn't Area 51 open on my phone?

Tags: bug, area-51, android

I use Android, and since the time I found out that we can suggest sites on Area 51,  I've not been able to open the site. When I browse for it, I only see a blank white page, and no site loads. Does the same thing happen to you?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Area 51 Mobile Site](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160436/area-51-mobile-site)

Comment: No repro on Galaxy S7.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. The other question asks why there isn't a mobile version. This question is from a user who cannot see Area 51 _at all_.  @Farzad64, what device do you have, which browser(s) do you use, and are there plugins installed in these browsers? Please [edit] that information into your question. It might help us to find the answer.

Comment: @S.L.Barth thank you very much for your good  attention, I open the site directly in stack exchange, I guess it uses my browser that is chrome, I don't remember all the plug-ins I have, but one is the avast security