# Image map in question renders in list

Tags: bug, status-norepro

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14152576/how-can-i-detect-a-mouseover-on-a-image-which-has-a-map-and-area

has this code in the question

```
<map name="A">
<area shape="rect" coords="0,0,100,100" href="XXXXX">
</map>
<img height="100" width="100" src="XXXX" usemap= "#A" >
```

which shows this in the lists (active questions and search)  like this in Chrome 23.0.1271.101 on OSX Mountain Lion

[image]

Here is the inspect element

```
<div class="excerpt">
                 … For example <span class="search-highlight">I</span> have an image:

<map name="A">
<area shape="rect" coords="0,0,100,100" href="XXXXX">
</map>
<img height="100" width="100" src="XXXX" usemap="#A"> <span class="search-highlight">How</span> <span class="search-highlight">can</span> <span class="search-highlight">I</span> <span class="search-highlight">detect</span> a <span class="search-highlight">mouseover</span> event on this image?

            </div>
```

**Update:** I see you have changed the search list. I cannot say I like it.
However in the current list you also seem to render html tags like H1:

[image]

Comment: Looks fine for me when I search for it: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=how+can+i+detect+a+mouseover

Comment: @Chris: It was edited though: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14152576/revisions

Comment: You mean when in review, isn't it?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Just the title though.

Comment: @Asad: Exactly; it's the title that's shown in listings (took me a second to get that it's a bug report about *listing* the question, not viewing it).

Comment: the editing was done by me because I thought the image was shown from the title but it is the actual snippet from the question that shows in the listing of the current questions - I uploaded a view from the seach done by @Chris

Comment: Closer: How can this possibly be off topic? It is a bug, it is no longer relevant, they tell me because they will change the way the list works but off topic???

Comment: What browser are you using? Do you have any plugins installed? Has anyone else seen this? So far we're unable to reproduce this.

Comment: See question. Chrome latest OSX Mountain Lion

Answer (score 6):

Update: we can't repro this on any search page or otherwise...you have a client script or something else in play. We are *definitely* encoding the specific examples you're providing.

---

Good thing we're [replacing the search page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160100/a-new-search-engine-for-stack-exchange) then, eh?

This won't be an issue for long since the way this is displayed is changing completely, probably within the next day, to the new format.  I'm currently working on the last of the infrastructure and style tweaks to the new results page before it goes live across the network as default.

Comment: It was not just the search page but the list of current questions too.

Comment: @mplungjan - hmm, it's definitely fixed in the search page, will take a look at the questions bit

Comment: Please see update. I am sorry, but I do nto see the search results update as an improvement. Very hard to read compared to the previous list that looked like the current list does now

Comment: @mplungjan the content you're seeing is a client-side issue specific to you...were definitely encoding there.  The preference in result format is a totally separate issue and covered elsewhere.

Comment: Ok, not a huge problem for me, just wanted to mention it.