# What technology is powering the search on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A new search engine for Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160100/a-new-search-engine-for-stack-exchange)

It looks potentially like Google? Or is it home-grown?

Comment: It was lucene.net but is now elasticsearch. See [A new search engine for Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160100/a-new-search-engine-for-stack-exchange).

Comment: awesome, that also answers my next question about filtering. :)