# find only old questions either by virtual year-tag or by a calendar date cutoff

Tags: support, search, old-questions

Is it possible to EXCLUDE from the search results questions asked *after* a certain arbitrary date? Or to get questions posed in a given year?

Let's say I'm maintaining a legacy app that is using a very popular software toolset that has a gazillion questions/answers on S.O. and unfortunately the different versions of this toolset do not have separate tags. And the API today is very different from what it used to be, such that recent questions and answers shed no light on my issue, and only make it harder to find the answer.

Would be great on Advanced Search to be able to specify a cutoff in some manner (clicking on a year tag, or supplying a literal e.g. "year < 2011" or "date < 2011-01-01" or "year=2009".

Comment: There is a newest tab, which you can use to order the question by date, but the disadvantage is that the result loses the relevance.

Answer (score 3):

Sure, using the `created:` operator with an appropriate range. For example, the following search will only [give you](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+created%3A2008..2010) all questions tagged [php](/questions/tagged/php) created between 2008 and 2010:

```
[php] created:2008..2010
```

[Nick](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/135201/nick-craver) was also [looking into](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160100/a-new-search-engine-for-stack-exchange#comment470390_160100) allowing you to set a maximum value in the form `created:..2010`, but this doesn't appear to work currently. `created:0..2010` works in a similar fashion and only requires one more character though, so not a big deal.

Comment: Thank you @Tim Stone.