# Search preferences (Q: / A: redundant spam)

Tags: feature-request, search, preferences

I don't know if this has long been the way SO operates when doing a search, but lately I've been annoyed when doing a search and finding a question followed by all several of its answers.  I know there's a search keyword for only questions / only answers, but it'd be nice if I could set default behavior via the site.

With myself, if I'm looking for an answer to a question I have, I first look to see if the question relates to what I'm looking for, then see what answers have been come up with.  Without knowing the context for an answer, I find it a lot less useful.  They of course show the title of the question, but often there's much that's omitted from an answer because it's implied in the question.  Which is why I've taken to searching only for questions.

It's particularly bothersome when I'm in a vague stage of looking for an answer, trying to narrow things down, because an unrelated question paired with unrelated answers really clogs up search results.

Basically, SE in general could benefit from search preferences, and setting a user default "show only answers" would be great.

Comment: I agree, it would be nice if the [new search engine](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160100/158605) defaulted to showing only Questions, or at least if it displayed two CheckBoxes for filtering for Questions or Answers easily without having to type `is:question` or `is:answer` in every one of the search queries.