# Why not group search results by thread?

Tags: feature-request, search

I like the new search, but the listing can become quite verbose. That is generally excellent because Stack Exchange is searching in more places. But now that you [don't roll up search results](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160100/98786) to the original question, it becomes quite difficult to remember *"that's not the question(s) I want … that's not the question(s) I want"* when the questions' answers appear dozens of times scattered throughout the listings.

**Why not group same-question entries together in the search results?**

I realize that each individual post wont be sorted strictly *"by relevance"*, but **the most relevant question *threads*** will be listed first… making it easier to skip over those entries once you decide that's not the question you're looking for.

Consider what we have now —

Apple SE > Search "Exchange contacts"

<sub>A: Exchange contacts do not appear in iCloud

A: Exchange contacts do not appear in iCloud

Q: iPhone Contact Sync

A: How to use Gmail contacts on an iPod Touch

A: Exchange contacts do not appear in iCloud

A: Exchange contacts do not appear in iCloud

A: How to use Gmail contacts on an iPod Touch

A: Exchange contacts do not appear in iCloud

A: Exchange contacts do not appear in iCloud

A: iPhone Contacts Sync

Q: Best way to transfer iphone contacts away from Exchange server

Q: Can I use Google's new CardDAV-based contacts sync to sync between my Exchange contacts and …

A: How to delete contacts from iPhone?

A: Can I use Google's new CardDAV-based contacts sync to sync between my Exchange contacts and …
:

etc, etc.

:</sub>

Once I realize I **don't** want that *iCloud* question… or that *iPod Touch* question… or that *sync* question — or a dozen others — it becomes extremely cumbersome to remember and search the listings for questions I *didn't* eliminate yet.

I'm *not* suggesting rolling up the results back to the original question… just **grouping** these posts together (I *like* seeing each answer-match with the text excerpt underneath). But once I eliminate the question entirely, it would be nice to scroll past those entries to continue my search… without all the noise of those entries reappearing over and over again in the search results.

Answer (score 3):

I agree that grouping would be a great feature, but it would still be best if they defaulted to *is:question*.

If they implement grouping, they could use the expand/contract boxes like directory structures use.