# ranking used in stackexchange

Tags: discussion

Just a curious question. When I type a question in stackoverflow, suggestions come up which shows similar questions. This clearly indicates there is a searching and ranking procedure going in behind. I was wondering which search technology stackoverflow uses under the interface, is it lucence, Sphinx, Terrier or any other?

Comment: elasticsearch. see [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160100/a-new-search-engine-for-stack-exchange)