# Abandoned tag not getting cleaned up during the nightly processes

Tags: bug, status-norepro, stack-overflow, tags

The [career-development](/questions/tagged/career-development) tag is now dead and gone on Stack Overflow, and has been since Monday.  The tag has since achieved undead status, because it won't seem to die during the nightly cleanup routines.

If you look at its [synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/career-development/synonyms) page, it shows four synonym tags, [career](/questions/tagged/career), [career-advice](/questions/tagged/career-advice), [employment](/questions/tagged/employment) and [job-hunting](/questions/tagged/job-hunting).  The page also shows that two questions are tagged with one of these tags:

[image]

However, if you enter each of these tags, there *aren't* any questions tagged; they all show up with "0 questions tagged".

So why does the synonym page think two questions are tagged, and why isn't this tag cleaning up?  Is the tag sticking around *because* it has synonyms?

Will the two mystery questions please step forward?

Comment: As Jehof answered, there were two _closed_ questions with that tag. I have deleted both questions now.

Comment: @Oded - That's weird; so simply clicking on a tag doesn't show closed questions by default?  Or did they not show up because they were locked?  If they didn't show up because they were locked, I would call that a bug, or at least "not very intuitive".

Comment: @Oded both were locked with "This question exists because it has historical significance" you sure deleting them is good idea? I tend to think the mods put some thought into locking instead of deleting.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - Good point. Though sometimes locking is a precursor to deletion. Lots of votes on those, so I reversed the deletion and simply removed the tag.

Comment: @Oded cheers, but think we found a bug: locked questions won't appear under the relevant tag search. Let me try and find more...

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - Not sure it is a bug. Could be [meta-tag:status-bydesign].

Comment: @Oded couldn't reproduce with other locked questions. Oh well, guess we can move on. :-)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - Call it a bug in the matrix.

Comment: @Oded careful, Agent Smith is watching! :D

Comment: @Oded I saw a white rabbit somewhere on SO

Comment: @Jehof - But did you see it _twice_ in a row?

Comment: @Oded only the black cat :-)

Comment: LOL @Minitech - that's one of my pet peeves too, I'm not sure how that slipped in there.  I'll call it another bug, because I sure didn't type that ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using the search [[career-development] is:q](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcareer-development%5D%20is:q) revealed the 2 questions. [One](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52176/447356), [Two](https://stackoverflow.com/q/611233/447356).

Comment: Yep. Both were locked, now deleted.

Comment: That's nifty, but it doesn't explain *why* the questions didn't show up by simply clicking a tag.  I would assume *all* non-deleted questions show up, but apparently locked questions are an exception?

Comment: @LBT my term uses the [elastic search](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160100/a-new-search-engine-for-stack-exchange), while clicking a tag does not and redirects to the tagged questions page. It seems that they are using diffrent approaches internally.