# Tags appear in lowercase in Google search results — should they be capitalized?

Tags: feature-request, tags, title, google, search-engine

Across the Stack Exchange network, tags appear before the user-given title of the question inside the HTML `<title>` element:

```
 <title>javascript - What does jQuery.fn mean? - Stack Overflow</title>
```

This typically happens when a relevant tag is not mentioned in the title — beneficial for [SERPs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_results_page). Here it's acceptable that the tag "html" is lower-case, despite the mismatch with "CSS" in the body of the question:

[image: tag in title]

In other cases, the lack of capitalization in tags within the `<title>` makes the Stack Exchange search result look "messy" and less curated, for example:

[image]

### What's the significance?

Folks seeing improper capitalization in SERPs may be less inclined to click. It could seem that a negligent person wrote the question and forgot to capitalize "google analytics". This can consciously or subconsciously signal that other content on SO is poor quality. too.

While this may seem minor (and perhaps it is), continual optimization can be a good way to stay on top and **improve click-through rate across the whole Stack Exchange network**.

### It's not just about Stack Overflow

SO is doing well in terms of visits from organic search, but the same cannot always be said about other, good-quality Stack Exchange sites. In both cases, there's always room for improvement — especially when not that difficult:

- Tags are automatically converted to lower-case.
- Changing to upper-case where appropriate can be crowd-sourced.

Capitalization won't be correct 100% of the time, but it's better than being wrong 100% of the time. Correct capitalization for tags would be:

- HTML
- jQuery
- Google Analytics
- string
- quantitative data

For SERPs, some could be re-written:

> String - Question goes here... - Stack Overflow
>    Quantitative data - Question goes here... - Stack Overflow

Some shouldn't:

> jQuery - Question goes here... - Stack Overflow

There's another question at the heart of this: **Why weren't tags capitalized to begin with?**

Comment: Why *should* tags be capitalised? That doesn't add any value, and only increases the changes of mistyping them.

Comment: Because a well-written `<title>` element can dramatically improve click-through rate in organic search results

Comment: As for mistyping, if you try and use upper-case letters in tags now, they are converted to lower-case — the implementation is already there and would just need to be reversed

Comment: I don't think Stack Overflow has to worry about SEO results; maintaining the proper capitalisation on tags is a huge extra stack of functionality, just for a (perceived) possibility that there is less click-through from Google?

Comment: I think if SE hasn't got a problem, it's the click-through rate from searchmachines. Also, so you'Re suggesting those tags: `[HTML]`, `[VB.NET]`, `[JAVA]`, `[GOOGLE-APP-ENGINE]` and `[WINDOWS-PHONE-8]`...capitalizing all tags is not an option.

Comment: @M.NightDemonbobby: **I'm not suggesting ALL-CAPS**, but proper, English capitalization: `Google-Analytics`, `Search-engine-optimization`, `HTML`, `JavaScript`, etc.

Comment: But `Html` is not correct...there's `html` closer to being correct...wait, are you still talking about display in the page title, or are you talking about tags in general?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: It's an estimate because I don't have access to StackExchange's CTR data — however, **as a rule of thumb, better `<title>` elements lead to better CTR**

Comment: @M.NightDemonbobby: two birds with one stone, why not have the appropriate, `HTML` appear in both SERPs and on-site?

Comment: So we'd basically need a pseudo-case-sensitivity? While entering the tags in the tag field they're case-insensitive, but at some point (like in the tag wiki) the proper cased version can be entered and set?

Comment: @M.NightDemonbobby: Exactly. And then presumably someone has to maintain the 'correct' capitalisation for each tag. Can you see the edit reverts for HTML versus html coming yet? I don't see the benefits outweighing the costs here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Yeah...I already thought about the "holy crusades of capitalization" and the resulting questions here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: because you can't see the benefits without Google Analytics data from StackExchange sites

Comment: @MartijnPieters: On the other site, can you imagine the storm unleashing when changing `[Java]` to `[JAVA]` and `[JavaScript]` to `[JAVAScript]`? That must be one hell of fun!

Comment: @M.NightDemonbobby, Java is always [Java](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(programming_language)), and JavaScript is [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) — the capitalization you suggest could be easily shot down... why would anyone try to change such a popular tag? A high reputation score is required already...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's arguably minor, but I find this difficult to disagree with.

In the context of a page title, `javascript` is not a tag (where the implicit convention is to use lowercase). When it is used to start a sentence, not doing it right *does* look odd. That's because it is wrong, twice. Sentences begin with a capital letter AND JavaScript is a proper noun.

One way to solve this without adding a new layer of specific rules ("HTML", "jQuery") would be **looking in the tag's wiki** for the correct way to write the term. A simple, case-insensitive `grep` would do.

This works for the top 10 tags without requiring any changes in the existing wiki text:

> C# is a multi-paradigm programming language...
>
> Java is an object-oriented language and runtime environment (JRE)...
>
> jQuery is a cross-browser JavaScript library...

Comment: Good idea with the Wiki!

Answer (score 2):

Using capitalization is a good idea, for SEO/ SERPs, for keeping our website organized, and because it respects proper English usage, for proper nouns. Many SO tags are proper nouns, e.g. JavaScript, MS Access. Despite that, I don't think SO should capitalize tags. This is why:

- Trademarks, company names and branding guidelines **must** be correct. That will make more work for moderators. Users *should* read tag wiki's for guidance e.g. **[word](/questions/tagged/word)** is only for questions about character strings, not for MS Word questions, but they often do not. See how many questions are improperly tagged with **[word](/questions/tagged/word)** now.
- [A new search engine for Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160100/a-new-search-engine-for-stack-exchange) debuted in December 2012. Regarding case:

  > Quoted phrases are exact matches except for case-sensitivity...

So search results are the same in count and content for text search,
`"As System Admin"` = `"as system admin"` and
`as system admin` = `As System Admin`.
The same is true for tags,
`tag:JavaScript` = `tag:javascript` and
`tag:C++` = `tag:c++`.
More accurately, mixed-case tags are converted to lower case, e.g. `[tag:JavaScript]` becomes **[javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)**.
So case-sensitivity is always ignored, won't even display for tags.

To capitalize tags, you need to change the SO search engine. Let's say that is easy to do. The new SO search was rolled out to all SE sites. That means "re-educating" **all SE sites** to use mixed-case tags. It will require time and energy. Consider whether it is worth it, and if now is the right time to do it.