# 'R' instead of 'r' in automatic tag-in-title mechanism

Tags: feature-request, tags, title

SO has a mechanism to add one of the tags, if not alread appearing in the question's title, to the html page title, like this: `{tag} - {question title}`. In addition, even if tags represent terms that are normally written with some upper-cased letters (such as `Python`), it appears in the html title lower-cased.

It may worth mentioning that the world wide web is not normally case sensitive.

Normally this is not a problem at all - it is quite normal to see `python` and `google-apps` and not `Python` or `Google Apps` everywhere; however, `r` is not as recognizable. Do you think there should be a rule exception here, and `r` should be added to the page title as `R - {question title}`?

Comment: We've been living with lowercase `c` and `c++` prefixes for ages, why shoud `r` be any different?

Comment: Same with `c`: I think that `r` is not as recognizable. Perhaps I'm wrong; it is just a feeling.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216225/is-there-any-reason-why-tags-are-lower-cased