# Give us better search-by-score syntax

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, search

> #### tl;dr: Give the score search operator ability to change between greater than and less than.

I just noticed that searching for `score:0` turns up *only* question with a score equal to 0. Searching for `score:1` gives *everything* with a positive score. (>=1)

I can live with these. But here's the big one: `score:-1`.

I would expect it to give all the *negatively* scored posts - there *is* a minus sign in there.

**But it doesn't**. It gives all the posts *>*=-1. Greater than?

So, my [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) is that we get more granular search options for score.

For example,

- `score:1` would show all posts with `score == 1`
- `score:1+` would show everything `score >= 1`
- `score:0` would show all posts with `score == 0`
- `score:-1` would show everything `score == -1`
- `score:-1-` would show al posts where `score <= -1`

In short, the operator *after* the number would show which direction to go with the matching. A minus sign means less than, a plus sign means greater than. No sign means exact.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

We use the [Google number range](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/136861?p=adv_operators&hl=en) style here which is simple: `term:<min>..<max>` where either `min` or `max` are optional as well.  Here are some examples:

- `score:-2..2` means `-2 to 2`
- `score:..2` means `<= 2`
- `score:2..2` means `== 2`
- `score:-2..` means `>= -2`

I agree it's not obvious since `score: 2` means `>= 2`, but I was not going to break an existing known syntax when adding the ability to search ranges as well.

Comment: I would have thought you add the [status-bydesign] tag.

Comment: @juergend there's a feature request in there...it's just already been completed in a different way.  Programmers will argue about search syntax all day, so we just choose the best route we could: match google.

Comment: Are you sure the last option works? [score:1203..1500](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=score%3A1203..1500) works nicely, but [score:1203..](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=score%3A1203..) gives 143,826 results...?

Comment: @Arjan it *did*, will look at the bug next time I'm at a comp

Comment: @Arjan yep there was a bug that creeped in, all fixed now - same range operator works on dates now as well (the optional part didn't before).

Comment: This is not really documented, other than in [the January announcement](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160100/a-new-search-engine-for-stack-exchange), right? Should we create a "How does search work"?

Answer (score 15):

Use `score:..-1` to search for posts having a score of `-1` or lower.

And searching for an exact score: I don't know a use case where that one is helpful.

Comment: Yeah, that's *totally* obvious. Who wrote the grammar for this search algorithm?

Comment: That should be on the advanced search page.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Oded, obviously. Bots aren't known for their excellent grammar.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII The range operator was borrowed from Google, where the unbounded lower range is simply an extension of that.

Answer (score 6):

As @juergen d already said you can use option `score:..-1` to search posts having score of -1 or lower.

In addition search engine allow to combine several score options in one search, e.g., for example, you can use request `score:..-1 score:-1` to search posts having exact score `-1` (e.g. `-1 and lower` and `-1 and greater` at same time).

Also, using option combination you can receive some complex search results, for example `score:32 score:..34` give posts with score from 32 to 34.

Comment: As a side note, you can combine it into a single option as `score:32..34`