# Update Help Center's "How do I search?" with shorthand values for advanced search options

Tags: feature-request, search, help-center

I have discovered that some advanced search options take shorthand values:

- "**is:q**" is equivalent to "**is:question**"
- "**is:a**" is equivalent to "**is:answer**"
- "**infavorites:1**" is equivalent to "**infavorites:mine**" <sup>1</sup>

These are not mentioned anywhere in the Help Center or the "Advanced Search Tips" on the search page. No big deal, but knowing these might save a tiny bit of time typing up a query, so maybe these shorthand values could be mentioned in "How do I search?"?

<sup>1 Well, this is no new discovery, saw this a long time ago when someone posted it on Meta</sup>

Comment: Odd, I'd think `infavorites:1` is only equivalent to `infavorites:mine` [for Jeff Atwood](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1), but you're right.

Comment: @Arjan looks like you have to used a leading zero to search for Jeff's favorites: `infavorites:01`

Comment: Luckily an octal 1 is equivalent to a decimal 1, @psubsee ;-) (But maybe that specific shortcut is not officially supported.)

Comment: Might also want to mention `user:me` and the `votes:min..max`, `votes:..max`, and `votes:min..` syntaxes (syntaxi? :P)

Comment: @Arjan actually I see it as a reason to not use 1 and 0 for boolean values :-)

Comment: **HOW did they fail to mention votes:min..max anywhere?** I had been writing SEDE queries to use upper limits, uptill now!

Comment: @AsheeshR I only knew about it because it was mentioned briefly in a meta post somewhere that I read once.

Comment: @psubsee2003 It is taking me a lot of restraint to not write in all caps right now. >:-(

Comment: @AsheeshR I can't find the post that I learned about it, but there's been some recent posts like: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188781/give-us-better-search-by-score-syntax

Comment: Related: [Add tips for Search by Range to the Advanced Search Tips](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192683/add-tips-for-search-by-range-to-the-advanced-search-tips?lq=1)

Comment: @Doorknob Actually, that info is already captured in the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/searching).  I'm guessing you want it in the advanced search tips?

Comment: Ah, and the dash/minus to exclude terms is not mentioned either?

Comment: @Arjan your are right, I saw "score" mentioned in relation to the range operators, but it isn't explicitly called out with all of the options.

Comment: @Doorknob, `user:me` is in the Help Center article, `votes..` is not but it is synonymous to `score` which is mentioned in the article.

Comment: `infavorites` became obsolete in the meantime, but there is [in:saves](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=in%3Asaves). See also: [Bookmarks have evolved into Saves](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382019).