# Add to the /help/searching pages that is:q and is:a exist as short forms of the is:question and is:answer operators

Tags: feature-request, search, help-center

In the "Miscellaneous Operators" section of the /help/searching pages, it says:

> `is:question` narrows results down to just questions, and `is:answer` returns only answers

But I don't see it documented anywhere in the page that one can also use `is:q` and `is:a`.

Could a sentence be added somewhere to also mention those short-forms? Perhaps like:

> `is:question` and `is:q` narrow results down to just questions, and `is:answer` and `is:a` return only answers.

It's not that this is critical information, but it just seems weird to me that these search operators aren't documented in the page that (to my understanding) is dedicated to documenting that kind of information.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Update Help Center's "How do I search?" with shorthand values for advanced search options](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193733/update-help-centers-how-do-i-search-with-shorthand-values-for-advanced-searc) - found from using a [site search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22is%3Aanswer%22+%22is%3Aa%22). This other post is from over 9 years ago so, although this issue is not particularly major, since it's quite easy to do, I hope somebody with appropriate authority actually does make an appropriate enhancement relatively soon.

Comment: yes it does! thanks and sorry.