# What is the question suggestion engine that powers Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, technology

What does Stack Exchange use in the backend to suggest related questions while typing a new question, or to show "related" questions on a question page?

Comment: Related, if not a duplicate: [Which tools and technologies are used to build the Stack Exchange Network?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-are-used-to-build-the-stack-exchange-network)

Comment: Interestingly this link doesn't contain any reference to ElasticSearch...

Comment: Yep. I'm curious to know whether it is just missing from the official list, or a bit of "creative" marketing by Elasticsearch.

Comment: [ElasticSearch](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160100/a-new-search-engine-for-stack-exchange) is used for the search box, not sure if the question suggestion engine uses the same engine or not.

Answer (score 1):

SO is listed as one of the Elasticsearch users, on http://www.elasticsearch.org/