# <code> tags are html-encoded on the flair page

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, flair, encoding

I just noticed this on [the flair page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/369/blorgbeard/flair):

> (to change the theme, add <code>?theme=clean</code> or <code>?theme=dark</code> or <code>?theme=hotdog</code> to the end of the image URL)

I assume it was intended that the `<code>` tags should be interpreted rather than rendered as text, i.e:

> (to change the theme, add `?theme=clean` or `?theme=dark` or `?theme=hotdog` to the end of the image URL)

Comment: Eeeeek! More of these?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build, rolling out probably Monday.  I'm headed to the beach in a few hours, so not building out when there's no one to watch it (lots of changes to go).

There are *massive* changes happening to our view system (as you've probably guessed by the syntax bugs lately), we're trying to keep them to a minimum while also not taking 5 years to complete the transition.

Truth is: expect some more of these, but we're testing as much as we reasonably can given the importance (e.g. a slight UI bug vs. a site breaker).  We hope you'll agree a bug slipping through every so often is worth it so we can move fast and move into other features and bugs that need love after this project.  Also, believe me when I say , these bugs are actually pretty rare given just how much has changed vs. how many bugs on meta as a result.

We appreciate the reporting of every one of these, we really do.  You guys and girls are helping us get through a major transition by reporting these so quickly...and, ya know, not physically harming us in the process.

Comment: Did you consider a post like you [did](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160100/a-new-search-engine-for-stack-exchange) for the new search, with *"tell us what you think here"* and *"would appreciate reports of any crazy behavior you see here"*, to report those minor issues?

Comment: @Arjan we did for a bit, but unlike a single feature these are all over the site, it's unlikely to actually be used as a single location for reporting anyway.

Comment: Okay, it'll be nice for the number of bugs you closed then ;-)