# Why didn't Stack Exchange use Google's custom search tool?

Tags: discussion, search

Google provides a pretty nifty tool for a website to do searching. Why didn't Stack Exchange use it?

Was it because it was not there when the site was created or does it do something more special than Google's?

Comment: You can pretty much get the same result by adding `site:stackoverflow.com` to any ordinary Google search.

Comment: Search was redesigned recently, but I don't know why they selected it vs Google, but my guess is the ability to have more control over the advanced search operators and the fact that you can use Google search already with "site:"

Comment: While I usually use Google to search for information as a user, the internal search is indispensable for moderator-related searches. That doesn't mean the Google Custom Search could not have also been implemented, but... just sayin'!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The advantage of making a custom search engine over using Google Custom search is that when you make a custom search engine you can create all sorts of [additional functionality](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160100/a-new-search-engine-for-stack-exchange) because you have access to all of the site data, not just the rendered HTML pages that Google indexes.

Google's search engine is fairly good at finding keywords and phrases within a rendered page, but there are lots of things that you can't do with Google's algorithm that you can do using a custom search engine that has access to all of the Stack Exchange backend data. For example, finding questions that have a particular combination of tags and sorting them in a particular order. For example [this query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php+mysql?sort=votes&pageSize=15) would be very difficult if not impossible to create with a Google custom search query.

In addition Google's data may not reflect recent changes because Google doesn't update it's data instantly whereas a custom built search engine always has access to the very latest data of what's on the site.

Comment: Google doesn't update instantly, but I have seen new Stack Overflow questions show up on Google within 3 minutes of being posted.  That's pretty close to instant.  Users looking for questions newer than that are probably not using search.