# Search from a link is breaking

Tags: bug, search

When I was searching for a question on stack overflow; I ended up on some answer someone posted here is the link to that question is: [Why does Opera Mini sometimes click the wrong link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055092/why-does-opera-mini-sometimes-click-the-wrong-link)

The guy answered with a link to stack overflow search and apparently it was breaking the link he posted is: https://stackoverflow.com/search/titles?like=why+does+opera+mini+sometimes+click+the+wrong+link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The search was drastically changed since then, now the syntax is:

```
title:why does opera mini sometimes click the wrong link
```

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3Awhy+does+opera+mini+sometimes+click+the+wrong+link

Comment: oh okay thanks. btw can you tell what kind of search StackOverflow is using? how are they implementing searches over multiple sites?

Comment: They're using [elasticsearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/) for the per-site search, more details [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160100/a-new-search-engine-for-stack-exchange). As for multiple sites, the "search all sites" in http://stackexchange.com/ is using Google Custom Search. (you can see "powered by Google" when searching for something there)