# How are vote totals and scores indexed in ElasticSearch in the Stack Exchange Engine

Tags: discussion, search

From [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160100/a-new-search-engine-for-stack-exchange) I understand that the Stack Exchange Engine uses ElasticSearch to power search.

How are results scored or sorted by Votes and Views, etc?

Does SE re-index a question every time an up or down vote occurs, or is there a batch process that periodically updates these parameters in the search index.  Or is there another way that votes and other metrics are integrated into search for scoring and sorting?