# Could we please use ElasticSearch stemmers tuned for non-English language sites?

Tags: feature-request, search, localization

**TLDR**: Can’t we please use [stemmers matched to site languages?](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-stemmer-tokenfilter.html)

According to [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160100) from Nick Craver and [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/283475) from Haney, our searches are using [the ElasticSearch stemmers](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/choosing-a-stemmer.html#stemmer-degree).
The problem is that stemmers have to be tuned for each particular language being used, or they generate too many false positives and false negatives. We should please use these, because [they appear to be available](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-stemmer-tokenfilter.html).

## Bad Searches

This problem is especially notable in the various non-English incarnations of Stack Overflow:

- In Spanish, the plural of *error* is not *errors* as in English, but *errores*. However, on the Spanish-language encarnación of Stack Overflow, [searching for the plural *errores*](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=errores) produces results very different from [searching for the singular *error*](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=error). That is incorrect because  these are the same lemma.
- In Portuguese, the word for a “function” is *função* in the singular, with the perfectly regular plural inflection *funções*.   However, on the Portuguese-language encarnação of Stack Overflow, [searching for the singular *função*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o) produces results crazily different from those obtained when [searching for the plural *funções*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es) there does. This is again wrong because those should resolve to the same lemma, as before.
- In Portuguese, the word for “variable” is *variável* in the singular, with the perfectly regular plural inflection *variáveis*.  However, [searching for the singular *variável*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=vari%C3%A1vel) produces somewhat different results than [searching for the plural *variáveis*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=vari%C3%A1veis) produces.

This is much worse when you have verbs. English gets to piggyback some of its singular–plural verb inflections atop noun inflections (think *drive, drives*), but more strongly inflected languages cannot do that. It’s not reasonable for people to have to think about all the tenses, aspects, persons, and moods just to find hits for the verb “return” in its many possible forms.

## Bad Tags

This same problem also surfaces in creating new tags, because the duplicate-of-singular/plural checker completely misses tags whose shift in grammatical number triggers “more things in other tongues than are dreamt of English philology”.

Because the Spanish, Portuguese, French, German, Italian *et cetera* Stack Exchange language sites use such tags in those languages, they’re always getting problems with tags that would be easily fixed simply by switching the stemmer to match the target non-English language.

Comment: Interesting note: ["ほし"](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22%E3%81%BB%E3%81%97%22), ["ほしい"](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22+%E3%81%BB%E3%81%97%E3%81%84%22), and ["ほしたち"](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22%E3%81%BB%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%81%A1%22) appear to return the same 128 results in Japanese. It appears to know they're all the same word plus inflection. However, I can't get the same behavior to work on the ENGLISH Stack Overflow (with English plurals), no matter what quotes. Have you been able to get *English* stems to work?

Comment: @Laurel For the most part, yes, English stems work fine. I don't know whether they’re using Porter or Snowball or whatnot. That said, those algorithms are notoriously bad in a few areas: alternate spellings like *color/colour*, *license/licence*, or *maneuver /manoeuvre*, as well as classical inflections imported from Latin or Greek along with the words borrowed into English such as *phenomenon/phenomena* or *crisis/crises*. But these are [known deficiencies](https://jbiomedsem.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/2041-1480-3-3) in those algorithms, and it isn’t quite so important IMHO.

Comment: @Laurel See also this comparison, the first [without Spanish-language stemming for inflectional morphology](http://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=me+está+devolviendo+errores) and the [second with the same](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=site:es.stackoverflow.com+me+está+devolviendo+errores&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8). See what I mean?

Comment: I now see things like [star](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=star) vs. [starring](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=starring) working, with the last [4 results](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=star+-starring) being "star" in code formatting. However, you lose most of the results when you search for [stars](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=stars), I think because it's a verb. It's obvious in http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=star+%22hit+your+head%22 vs. http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=stars+%22hit+your+head%22