# HEIC is for horses…

Tags: feature-request, bug, search

Seriously, I was attempting to search for threads in the Photography Stack Exchange site and [did a search for “HEIC” with sorting ordered by “Votes”](https://photo.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=HEIC) and it seems the search logic — whatever that might be — is interpreting “[HEIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Efficiency_Image_File_Format)” as “Hey” which is… Not really great. Screenshot below.

Are there exception lists for known acronyms and file extensions to improve sorting? Can HEIC be added to that if possible.

[image: Screenshot showing “HEIC” being interpreted as “Hey.”]

And [as noted in a comment by animuson](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/350457/heic-is-for-horses#comment1173247_350457), [adding quotes to “HEIC” in the search ends up giving the expected results](https://photo.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%22HEIC%22); screenshot below.

But honestly adding quotes to a single word doesn’t seem like an intuitive solution for most people who will be casually searching for something like “HEIC.”

[image: Screenshot showing adding quotes to “HEIC” provides desired results.]

Comment: That looks like stemming is responsible, though I wouldn't have expected this term to be affected by stemming at all.

Comment: I've never heard of an exception list for that system, and I don't believe one exists. But there has got to be a way to identify situations where Elasticsearch is changing what it is looking for and display a note at the top like Google does. "Showing results for {altered}; search instead for {original}" would be great there. Because searching for `"HEIC"` (with quotes) works perfectly.

Comment: This is a good post, but to be honest I just upvoted it for the title.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Stack Exchange's search uses [Elasticsearch](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160100/295232) with default 'stemmers' for English, which try to [combine variations of the same word](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/287711/295232). It's possible to [tune those stemmers](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-stemmer-override-tokenfilter.html) but it's a lot of work and I guess it won't be done for individual cases like this one.

If I would encounter such a case, I'd immediately spot it (you can see the highlighted **hey**s in the search results) and either

- [search for `"HEIC"`](https://photo.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22HEIC%22)
- [use Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Aphoto.stackexchange.com+heic)