# Why does searching on Stack Overflow and other communities not have spelling correction?

Tags: feature-request, search, spelling

Why does searching on Stack Overflow and other communities not have spelling correction? Something similar to Google's spelling correction...

Answer (score 9):

It does have some kind of spelling correction. [Searching for 'spellings' and sorting on newest](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=spellings) gives your question as one of the top results, even though it does not contain the word 'spellings':

[image]

This is the result of using so-called [stemmers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/287711/295232) in Elasticsearch, the repository powering the Stack Exchange search.

If you frequently misspell words, it's better to install a browser extension which underlines wrongly spelled words in editable fields, and offers a context menu to correct them.

Comment: I think you're wrong about this post "not containing 'spelling'", this question contains the word spelling. But the SE search engine knows the difference between plurals and singulars, that's why this questions appears.

Comment: I think the search engine probably doesn't know the difference between singular and plural, but stores and queries the roots of words, essentially erasing the difference.

Comment: @mindstormsboi I wrote that the question doesn't contain spelling***s***.