# How do people find out about new questions?

Tags: support

When I ask a question (usually on Stack Overflow) I often get answers or comments very quickly. How do people know my question has been asked? Along the same lines, if I'm interested in helping to answer a question about a certain topic, how do I hear about new questions on that topic?

Is it possible to subscribe to a tag and be notified when a new question that uses that tag is posted? That would seem like the best solution, but I don't see a way to subscribe to tags.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Multiple ways!

You can add tags as you can add "Favorite Tags" where questions with that tag will be highlighted:

[image]
[image]

as seen in blue here at Meta Stack Exchange. You can also click on a tag to see all of its questions that uses it, with a filter option called "newest" ([example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discussion) with the [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)). With some sites like Beta sites, questions don't come out that often and can be found just by looking through the newest questions.

As Werner said, you can subscribe to a tag to "receive emails or via RSS" (picture also in Werner's answer):

[image]

Answer (score 3):

People who find relevant content to your question most likely have the following two attributes:

- Have been around long enough and have seen numerous, similar questions;
- Know how to search (either using [the site's native search functionality](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160100/168244), or via Google)

You can subscribe to tags and receive emails or via RSS. Visit the specific site's tag page - `http://<site>/tags` (or anywhere there is a tag you're interested in), search for a tag you're interested, hover over it and select `subscribe` or `rss`:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Many users will just put a browser tab on the "Active" or "New" sub-tab of their favorite tag and refresh when the websocket says new questions are available. There is even a helpful title change when new questions show up.