# Why is code excluded from phrase search?

Tags: bug, search, exact-phrase-search

I tried to find some of my old answers on Stack Overflow but did not get the results I expected. The problem seems to apply all SE sites. I tested dba.SE and Super User, and they exhibit the same problem.

The ["Advanced Search Tips"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22irrelevant%22) advertise:

> exact    "words here"

There is isn't any mention this would *exclude* code. Nothing is mentioned in the [help page](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22irrelevant%22), either.

[This related post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160100/169168) explicitly claims it should work for code or symbols:

> Quoted phrases are **exact** matches except for case-sensitivity, for
>   example, [you can search for code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22COUNT%28*%29%20AS%20UpVotes%22) or [symbols](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22*=%22).

But that does not seem to work as advertised.

`user:939860 "WITH RECURSIVE"` returns four results (the phrase appears outside code blocks).

`user:939860 WITH RECURSIVE` (no double quotes) returns 108 results - obviously ignoring the noise word "with". Most of the results have the exact phrase `WITH RECURSIVE` - inside code blocks.

This does the job, mostly:

```
user:939860 code:"WITH RECURSIVE"
```

But:

- The keyword `code:` seems to be a secret, neither mentioned in the "Advanced Search Tips" nor on the help page.
- Now I get *only* code results. The attempt to use `OR` does not work: <strike>`user:939860 code:"WITH RECURSIVE" OR "WITH RECURSIVE"`</strike>
- The more useful default would be to search in all text *including* code to begin with. It is counter-intuitive that code is excluded. After all, that seems to be the behavior with plain words (not phrases). Example: `user:939860 RECURSIVE`. *That* includes code and non-code by default.

Is phrase search broken in this respect or am I missing something?