# Different results for plurals of some words

Tags: bug, search, plurals

I just wasted a lot of time trying to find the question [What are the differences between buttons and links?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/5493/83293)

I searched for...

- [`button link`](https://ux.stackexchange.com/search?q=button+link+score%3A52..53)
- [`button links`](https://ux.stackexchange.com/search?q=button+links+score%3A52..53)
- [`buttons link`](https://ux.stackexchange.com/search?q=buttons+link+score%3A52..53)

...but did not find anything.

I needed to search for [`buttons links`](https://ux.stackexchange.com/search?q=buttons+links+score%3A52..53) to find it.

Even on this site you can tell that they show different results:

- [`buttons`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=buttons): 1,658 results
- [`button`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=button): 7,996 results

Some search results are wildly inconsistent:

- [`"plural"`](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22plural%22): 9,464 results
- [`"plurals"`](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22plurals%22): 619 results
- [`plural`](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=plural): 10,038 results
- [`plurals`](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=plurals): 10,022 results
- [`plurals -plural`](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=plurals+-plural): 0 results
- [`plural -plurals`](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=plural+-plurals): 15 results
- [`plural -"plurals"`](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=plural+-%22plurals%22): 9,373 results
- [`plurals -"plural"`](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=plurals+-%22plural%22): 457 results
- [`plural -"plural"`](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=plural+-%22plural%22): 472 results

In contrast, [`scraper`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=scraper)/[`scrapers`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=scrapers) returns results for both forms.

The expected result is, according to [Nick Craver](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160100/323179):

> If not in a quoted phrase, words will now be stemmed.

Comment: No. *button* and *buttons* are different words, just as *amp* and *per* and *sand* and *ampersand* are all different. Showing things that people have not searched for, just because they share a substring, makes no sense.

Comment: @Nij what is the difference in meaning  between button  and buttons? If you tell me that the latter is plural I will not find it amusing.

Comment: @Nij The expected behavior is that words will be stemmed, as the edit I just made shows.

Comment: So should a search for *buttons* also turn up *button*? Yes? Great, we now have to teach this search thing of yours which words ending with S are the plural of some other legitimate word.

Comment: @Nij comment/comments, post/posts, question/s, badge/s, suspension/s etc. Will I get different results if I forget to add the "s" suffix?

Comment: @Nij Can you explain the behavior I'm seeing? Why does `plural -"plural"` not return 0 results if it's supposed to be an exact match?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying with the Exact match pattern. It will return the exact matched keywords result only.

In case of want to search with partial match, please try [button* link*](https://ux.stackexchange.com/search?q=button%2A+link%2A+score%3A52..53), it will result the same as [buttons links](https://ux.stackexchange.com/search?q=buttons+links+score%3A52..53)

As per the [search help page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching),

> Use wildcard searches to broaden results; add an asterisk (*) anywhere in the word, like `encour*` or `Ex*nge`.

So, this is not a bug.

Comment: Why does `plural -"plural"` not return 0 results if not using quotes is supposed to be an exact match? That's a bug.