# Don't treat code blocks as spaces when searching

Tags: bug, search, code-formatting, code-block, whitespace

I wanted to find all the posts containing the phrase `call or call`. In my case, I'll demonstrate on Stack Overflow, but this happens on Stack Exchange search too, so this isn't just an Stack Overflow  issue. So, I typed `"call or call"` into the search bar. It says this, so I imagined it would only search for that exact phrase.

> `"words here"` exact phrase

[Here is the search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22call+or+call%22) if you want to try it. Unfortunately, as I looked through them, many did *not* contain the exact words "call or call". As [cigien](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8372853/cigien) realized, the search is also finding results for `call [inline code here][optional punctuation] or call`. So it appears that in searching, it will also return results where, if my search contains a space, the space can really also be inline code or punctuation. I tried running [a SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1630071) to show results for `call or call`, which returned what I expected (only results that matched that exactly.

Another example is `"use to"`. Typing that in [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22use%20to%22%20is%3Aa) returns results for things like

> use `git reflog` to determine...

You can find similar results if you search for `"use for"` or any two words that would commonly have inline code between them.

Also, [A new search engine for Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160100/a-new-search-engine-for-stack-exchange) says

> Quoted phrases are exact matches except for case-sensitivity, for example, you can search for code or symbols.

That makes me suspect this is a bug, and not the intended behavior.

I'd like it to return exact results only, or *maybe* results where the spaces in the query are considered "any whitespace character" in search, but I don't think considering inline code as spaces makes sense.

Can search be updated to only search for my exact phrase when I use double quotes and not automatically substituting spaces in "exact match" queries with "space or punctuation or inline code", please?

Comment: "or" could be interpreted as a Boolean operator. Here is [a search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22you+are+trying+to+represent%22) that seems to work as intended. Can such operators be escaped?

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum Huh... I'd still expect a raw string to not have operators apply to it, although you could be right

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum The OR operator is only for tag searches: `[widgets] or [geegaws]` It does not work with other searches. See ["sort array"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22sort+array%22) which has 4227 results, ["reverse array"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22reverse+array%22) which has 401 results but ["sort array" or "reverse array"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22sort+array%22+or+%22reverse+array%22) does not combine them, instead brings zero results.

Comment: "*Searching for [python] (i.e., the Python tag) gives just under 4.9 million results*" what is the exact search text? To the best of my knowledge if you type in `[python]` in the search you would get the Python page. Clicking on the tag does the same. There is actually a separate functionality for tag searching (the URL you go to is `/tagged/<searched tags>`) and other searches - anything that includes text (the URL is `/search?q=<search text>`). They would give you somewhat different results in some occasions but if you *only* search for a tag, you trigger the tag search feature.

Comment: @VLAZ I meant literally typing `[python]` ( https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D ) which is labeled "search within a tag", which I'd expect to have the same number of questions as the Python tag (unless I add more to my search than "anything in that tag"). For comparison, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) is it through the tag menu, which displays a different nmber of questions

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D leads me to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python which is also the same page you go to if you click on the Python tag. If you did somehow go to the `/search` page, then the discrepancy of numbers of results is probably because it lists questions *and answers*. So `[python] is:q` should show the correct(-er) number of results. I'd expect [some small discrepancy](https://shouldiblamecaching.com/) maybe within 100 or less but not anything close to 2mil vs 4mil

Comment: Ohh, I see. I'll roll back the edit, I didn't realize that

Comment: Yep, just checked: [`[python] is:q`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+is%3Aq) has ~2 million results and  [`[python] is:a`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+is%3Aa) has ~2.8 million results, so that matches the total of 4.9 million you saw.

Comment: Just noticed this today when a search for "like and share" was returning [answers like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24345855): "Operations like `=` and `append` share a reference..." I think stripping out punctuation is fine, but not entire words.