# How am I able to see the view count if I haven't earned the established user privilege at 1k reputation?

Tags: bug, reputation, privileges

The [established user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/established-user) privilege is awarded at 1k rep. However, I'm still able to see the view count on a post despite not having earned the established user privilege.

Here is proof, currently the vote count for [Don't treat code blocks as spaces when searching](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/381481/dont-treat-code-blocks-as-spaces-when-searching):

[image]

But as you can see, I'm far away from this privilege:

[image]

- I'm using Chrome version 104.0.5112.102